# How to know everytime how to define my variables/placeholders shape in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to learn tensorflow, I already did some exercises with simple perceptron with datas like, one features, one output.

I'm now trying with more features but, I have a problem with my variable/placeholder shape.
I thought I learned how it works, but it seems that I was wrong.
I would like to know how to get the good values in general so I won't get this kind of problem anymore.

Here's my code :

[in]:

```
print(inputX.shape)
print(inputY.shape)
```

[out]:

(50, 9)
(50, 1)

[in]:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 9]) #features
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1]) #labels
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 9])) #Weights, nb of labels[x,x]nb of features
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1])) #[x]nb of features
Y = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W),b))
```

[out]:

Dimensions must be equal, but are 9 and 1 for 'MatMul_21' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,9], [1,9].

I gess the problem is the 1 but I don't get where it come from.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You are trying to multiply a <value> x 9 matrix with a 1 x 9 matrix and that is what is wrong. I suspect your weight definition is wrong. What if you transpose that matrix before multiplication?

Comment: It looks like it change nothing when I try to transpose it, Tensorflow still telling me the same thing

Comment: You still get error if you write this `Y = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x), W),b))` instead of this `Y = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W),b))`

Comment: Ho, no, it work, I must did it in a wrong way... Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here, as I see that, you are trying to do a wrong Matrix Multiplication. The basic rules of which can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)

If you change your last line to

```
Y = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x), W),b))
```

Then it wont give you the error related to dimension anymore.

Comment: I will look at this link, thanks for the answer and for the help !

Comment: Sadly, it give me now an another problem when I try to run my session: Incompatible shapes: [50,1] vs. [9,9]
I tried with another dataset but the error is the same... Any idea how should I do in this case ?

Comment: It is a different case. I think your formation of data set is wrong. Do you hav the ideas of how basic datasets should look like in a ML problem?

Comment: I use some CSV files, all the values are numerical and I got an output that is always 1 or 0 (I will try with way more output possibilities when I will know how to do with just 2 every time)

Comment: please go through the first tutorial in Tensorflow website, especially [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners#softmax_regressions). You need to understand a little bit of the underlying math in order to use ML effectively. Also you can read [Deep Learning Book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) By Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville. This is a very effective book and without this base you will be totally lost.

Comment: To point out (Given the fact that I have no idea of your dataset) your weight definition is wrong at the first place. It should be `W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([9, 1]))` so number of features X number of classes (outcomes) I believe and in that case you probably do not need to transpose it anymore.

Comment: I will follow your advices, I must admit that i'm kinda lost with tensorflow and Ml. Thanks for you time and your answers, it's really kind !

Comment: You are very welcome. ML is a highly advanced and complicated field of CS. Please consider investing significant amount of time before you can create and run a good model by yourself. That said, do not give up it is a LOT of fun :)